# generate HTML <select> with title inside each <option> to apply the msDropDown plugin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, drop-down-menu

I am using the [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) gem to upload images to my application.
Now I need to display the images in a dropdown list that is part of a form.
I am trying to use the [msDropDown](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown). However, I need to generate a `title="#path for the image"` inside each `<option>` of my `<select>`.
At the moment I have:

```
<%= f.select(:style_id, Style.all.map{ |p| [p.dropdown, p.id] }, {:include_blank => 'Select Style | Construction'}, class: "bigselect" ) %>
```

The above generates the following HTML:

```
<select class="bigselect" id="item_style_id" name="item[style_id]"><option value="">Select Style | Construction</option>
  <option value="1">first</option>
  <option value="2">second</option>
  ...
</select>
```

I need to edit my RoR select code to generate the HTML below.

```
<select class="bigselect" id="item_style_id" name="item[style_id]"><option value="">Select Style | Construction</option>
  <option value="1" title="#path for the image">first</option>
  <option value="2" title="#path for the image">second</option>
  ...
</select>
```

The `#path for the image` is the column `image` on the same Model as the `dropdown` column on my select. So, using carrierwave should be something like `p.image_url(:thumb)`.
Any ideas on how to generate this `title`?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to pass title as html options to `<option>` elements

```
<%= f.select(:style_id, Style.all.map{|p| [p.name, p.id, :title => p.image_url(:thumb)]}, ....
```