# How to render images in rails3 select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionview, actionviewhelper

I want to render dropdown list in form with images as options. How to achieve this in rails3?

Answer (score 1):

I like the [msdropdown](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown). You can add the path for the image in the `title` tag:

```
<select>
  <option value="1" title="#path for the image">first</option>
  <option value="2" title="#path for the image">second</option>
   ...
</select>
```

In Rails, you can add the title doing something like:

```
<%= f.select(:yourcolumn, Model.all.map{|p| [p.name, p.id, :title => p.image_url(:thumb)]}
```

I have faced a similar problem some time ago: [generate HTML <select> with title inside each <option> to apply the msDropDown plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050128/generate-html-select-with-title-inside-each-option-to-apply-the-msdropdown-p)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this plugin http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown there is no option to do it directly in Rails.