# Rails: Create a select box that shows images, passes path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, select

So, I have a rails controller that has a @images set, which has the paths for the images I want to select from, ready to use in image_tag. The table for this object has a field for image_path. In the new view for this object, I want to have a select box that displays each image from @images and passes the text of that into the form, where it will be saved to the object's database.

Right now, I have code that makes a select box showing the filename:

```
= f.select :image_path, @images
```

and code that can show all of the images

```
-@images.each do |image|
  = image_tag image
```

What I want is for the select box to show the images and pass the paths as it already does.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the default rails select tags, though there is a jquery plugin called [jquery image dropdown](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown)
See this [SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522965/how-to-render-images-in-rails3-select) for more information.