# How do I add a img to a select tag?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, html-select

Im wanting to add an image to the following line in ruby.

My select tag is as follows

`<%= select_tag :type, options_for_select(['All'] | shop.types.map{|o| [o, o.downcase] }),class: 'hometest' %>`

This is the image with the class I wish to place inside.

`<%= image_tag 'dropdown.svg', class: "dropdownimg" %>`

Answer (score 0):

The `select_tag` in Rails just uses the native HTML `<select>`: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

It is not possible to use anything other than text within this tag.

See this SO post for some options that could work for you: [How to render images in rails3 select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522965/how-to-render-images-in-rails3-select)